# Sick TiM310 Laser scanner not publishing to the topic

Tags: ros, laser, ros-fuerte, sick

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to get my SICK TIM 310 laser working with ROS. I installed the ROS package sick_tim3xx in Fuerte on Ubuntu 12.04
When I run roslaunch sick_tim3xx sick_tim3xx.launch, I get following output and nothing gets published on the topic.

WARNING: received less fields than expected fields (actual: 124, expected: 580), ignoring scan

What could be possibly wrong with the laser? why is it giving only 124 fields instead of 580?
I'd really appreciate your help
thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65622/sick-tim310-laser-scanner-not-publishing-to-the-topic/) by [theblackpearl](https://answers.ros.org/users/5200/theblackpearl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2013-06-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've solved this issue with @theblackpearl over email; here's a summary of the solution:

- The mystery scanner in question is actually the new TiM 510 (which is not sold yet), even though it was labeled as a TiM 310.
- It provides 91 measurements per scan over a 270° scan angle, instead of 271 (like the TiM 310 does). Also, it doesn't provide intensities. This is why each datagram is only 124 instead of 580 bytes.
- The specs for the datagram format are yet to be released; I've written a [quick hack](https://github.com/uos/sick_tim3xx/tree/sick_tim510) to make the scanner work until proper support can be added to the `sick_tim3xx` package.

**Edit 04/2022:** Apparently, I removed the "quick hack" branch in 2013. If anybody is still looking for this, the contents of the branch were merged in the main branches as the `sick_tim310_1130000m01` node.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2013-06-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1